# MacVim + sparkup.vim

Tags: vim

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is not working.

So I just installed sparkup and everything works as expected, however when I try doing something like this:

```
nav > ul > li*4 > a[href][target=_blank] { Some link } (CTRL + E}
```

It expands just fine... I get something like this:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
                <li>
                        <a href="" target="_blank"> some link </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="" target="_blank"> some link </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="" target="_blank"> some link </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="" target="_blank"> some link </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

with the cursor position being within the first href... that's great, i can type in my href and press CTRL + N to navigate to the next stop point, but when I press CTRL + P it just gives me some dropdown list of items as if it were some kind of quick access to attributes or something... it doesn't go back to the previous stop point - Anyone know why or how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like there's another plugin gobbling up CTRL + P and doing some sort of autocompletion (maybe SuperTab)?  Try searching your .vim/plugin dir for <c-p> and see if anything else binds it.

Comment: That completion menu is native to vim.  `Ctrl-p` and `Ctrl-n` are "Complete words in this file" by default.  I guess sparkup is supposed to override both?

Comment: Keep in mind I am performing a CTRL + N (capitol N) and same with P it's capitol.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparkup doesn't support going backward, only forward with `<C-n>`: it doesn't even have a non-mapped function for that.

I guess you could try to hack it in or ask for this feature to the author.